# How to use environment variables in a PHP script using getenv()?

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm having trouble using `getenv()` in my PHP script. I've set the environment variable in my bash session:

`MYPATH=~/some/kind/of/path`

I've verified it's working with:

```
echo $MYPATH
```

**My question:**

Why is `getenv( 'MYPATH' )` returning `false` when I use it in my PHP web script? I'd expect */home/user/some/kind/of/path* to be returned.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: Are you running this PHP script from the command line?

Comment: No. I'm running it through my web server (Apache). I've updated my question to make that clear.

Comment: Then you need to set the environment variable for Apache.... either add it to your vhosts file or .htaccess file using [SetEnv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/env.html); setting it in your bash will only make it available from the CLI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're setting var and invoking php script right after taht, in the same shell session, you must to **export** the environment var:

[image]

When some variable is exported to environment, it is passed in to environment of all descendents processes. As php creates a new "subprocess" you must share the "environment" and vars with it and this is what happens when using export statement.

Comment: I'm not running the PHP script through the CLI, sorry for not making that clear. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access this environment variable through PHP in the web SAPI, then you need to set the environment variable in the configuration for your webserver, e.g. in the `vhost` section using [SetEnv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html)

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>
    ...
    SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME variable_value
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It seems I needed to `export MYPATH`. See [35293297/1709033](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35293297/1709033)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the file path of the current directory, you can use this:

```
define("FILE_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
echo FILE_ROOT;
```

Comment: In my case, this isn't what I want to do. But thanks for the suggestion.